# Removing the "category" and "tag" section from every DNN page

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have installed DNN Alpha version 5.4.0.107

every page has a category and tag section at the end of it. How do i get rid of this?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options.

- You can [download another skin](http://www.snowcovered.com/Snowcovered2/Default.aspx?tabid=295&categoryid=592&sortby=Price-ASC) and use that instead
- You can download an older version of DNN (5.2 or before) and grab the Minimal Extropy skin package (from the Install/Skin folder)
- You can edit the skin files (in Portals/_default/Skins/MinimalExtropy) to remove the Tags element